# Javassist overwriting existing annotations

Tags: javassist

Already existed annotations present at the top of class are removing and whatever i added using Javassist are adding but not taking any effect.

suppose

```
@Entity
class Master
{

      //variables
     //getters and setters
}
```

What i need is to add extra annotation @Table(name="Master",schema="Master_Database")
to be added via Javassist dynamically to the above class 'Master'.

What i'm facing is @Entity is removed and @Table is successfully added.
This causes loss of functionality of eclipseLink auto generation of entity classes.
Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as:

```
ctClass.getClassFile().addAttribute(attributeInfo);
```

That should not remove existing annotations. For helping you further we would need to know how you added the annotation.

But are you bound to Javassist? Have a look at [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) (I am the author) which makes adding annotations a rather easy excercise:

```
TypePool pool = TypePool.Default.ofClassPath();
TypeDescription type = pool.describe("name.of.class");
Class<?> enhanced = new ByteBuddy()
  .redefine(type, ClassFileLocator.ForClassFile.ofClassPath())
  .annotation(new Table() {
    ...
  })
  .make()
  .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
  .getLoaded();
```

Comment: Hi Rafael, Thanks for your response....ByteBuddy and Javassist helps in adding annotations dynamically but efficient for single or two classes but i have more number of classes, which is not efficient. Anyways Thank you Rafael and thanks for the ByteBuddy suggestion, really great.